# EditText inside of clickable Listview Item

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` has has a few items in it. Each item can be clicked to display another view.

However in each item, I have a `EditText` that holds a quantity that should be editable.

The `ListView` currently has `.setOnItemClickListener()` and works fine if the item layout has `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

But then the `EditText` can no longer be focus able and therefore you cannot change the quantity.

Here is my `ListView`:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvOrderItems"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:layout_weight=".35"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:divider="@null" />
```

And here is my Item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgItemImage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtItemName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/lato"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#666666" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtItemPrice"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
            android:text="$0.00"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/lato"
            android:text="Qty:" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtTabletQty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/textbox_background"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I read on another post saying "Android doesn't allow to select list items that have focusable elements (buttons)."

But I need the `EditText` to be focus able for the user to click on it and change the value inside. Unless I am missing something?

My Adapter code is quite standard. Here is the `getView` code:

```
ViewHolder holder;

if (view == null) {

    // CREATE
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_items, null);
    holder.txtItemName = view.findViewById(R.id.txtItemName);
    holder.txtItemPrice = view.findViewById(R.id.txtItemPrice);
    holder.imgItemImage = view.findViewById(R.id.imgItemImage);
    holder.txtTabletQty = view.findViewById(R.id.txtTabletQty);
    holder.imgBtnClearItem = view.findViewById(R.id.imgBtnClearItem);

    // SET
    view.setTag(holder);

} else {

    // SET
    holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

}

// SET
holder.txtTabletQty.setText(cartItem.get("quantity"));
holder.txtTabletQty.setId(position);

holder.txtTabletQty.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {

        if(!hasFocus){

            // UPDATE QUANTITY

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Post the adapter code...

Comment: @SantanuSur I have, most solutions are just to get the `EditText` to work. But I need both to be clicked and respond differently

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 I have edited with the `getView` code of the adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Work-Around Don't use `setOnItemClickListener` for item click. Set the click listener in your `getView()` method.

Inside `getView()`

```
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Item Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Then remove `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` from the list item layout.

So the `Edittext` can receive focus.